# Smallest integer $x$ for which 10 divides $2^{2013} - x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

Find the smallest integer $x$ for which 10 divides $2^{2013} - x$

Obviously,

$x \equiv 2^{2013} \pmod{10}$

But how can I reduce $x$?

Comment: Hint: look at the last digit of small powers of two: you will get 2,4,8,6,2,4,8,... Can you see the pattern? Can you prove that the pattern holds?

Comment: Wojowu's way is the simplest.However you can also use repeated squaring,Euler's theorem etc. .

Comment: Yes, it goes in $2, 4, 8, 6$

Comment: How do I do wojowu's way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $$2^{1} (\bmod 10) \equiv 2 \\ 2^{2} (\bmod 10) \equiv 4  \\  2^{3} (\bmod 10) \equiv 8 \\  2^{4} (\bmod 10) \equiv 6 \\  2^{5} (\bmod 10) \equiv 2 \\  2^{6} (\bmod 10) \equiv 4 \\  \vdots$$ leads us to see  $$2^{n} (\bmod 10) = 2^{n+4} (\bmod 10)$$
Hence $$2^{2013} (\bmod 10) = 2^{(4\cdot 503)+1} (\bmod 10) \\ = 2^{1} (\bmod 10)$$ Now what can you add or subtract from $2^{1} (\bmod 10)$ to make it a multiple of $10$?

Comment: Mmmmm. how is $2^{4\cdot 503 + 1} \equiv 2^1$ ?

Comment: @Amad27 it follows from $$2^{n} (\bmod 10) = 2^{n+4} (\bmod 10)$$ since $$2^{1} (\bmod 10) = 2^{1+4} (\bmod 10) \\ = 2^{1+4+4} (\bmod 10) \\ \vdots \\ 2^{1+4+4+4+ \ldots} (\bmod 10)$$ and if you add $503$ fours to $1$, you get $2013$

Comment: Okay, just a query. How can you say that $2^{1 + 4} \equiv 2^{1 + 4 + 4} \pmod{10}$ ?

Comment: You also have to mod by $10$ the LHS of what you have above. I suppose you could prove inductively that $2^n$ and $2^{n+4}$ have the same remainder, or it could be done by writing out a few terms as I did in my answer. But in the query above, you can see that $2^{5}=32$ and hence $2^{5}(\bmod 10)=2$ while $2^{9}=512$, hence  $2^{9}(\bmod 10)=2$, so  $2^{5}(\bmod 10)= 2^{9}(\bmod 10)$

Comment: I dont understand still. How is $2^n \equiv 2^{n + 4 + 4} \pmod{10}$ (+1) By the way!

Comment: @Amad27 no problem! I will do my best to clarify. I am not saying that $2^n \equiv 2^{n+4+4} (\bmod 10)$, I am saying that the *remainders* of $2^n$ and $2^{n+4+4}$ are equal, which is to say $$2^n (\bmod 10) = 2^{n+4+4} (\bmod 10)$$

Comment: Sorry for trouble, but how are the remainders equal?

Comment: @Amad27 no trouble. Do the first six lines of my answer make sense? That is the pattern you look for in these types of problems

Comment: Yes, I see the pattern, $n = 1, 2$ and $n=2, 4$ and $n=3, 8$ and $n=4, 6$.

Comment: @Amad27 right. So what ever remainder $r$ there is on $2^n$, you know that the remainder cycles through $2,4,8,6$ and will come back around to $r$ for every addition of $4$ to $n$

Comment: I get it, this is the best answer here. However, can this work for example, $2^{2013} \pmod{8}$ for example?

Comment: @Amad27 Thank you! And great followup question. One way you can check is to do what I did in the first six lines of my answer. The practice will be very helpful for future problems like this :)

Answer (score 3):

As $(2^{2013},10)=2$

let us find $2^{2013-1}\pmod{\dfrac{10}2}$

Now $2^2\equiv-1\pmod5\implies2^{2012}=(2^2)^{1006}\equiv(-1)^{1006}\equiv1\pmod5$

Now as $a\equiv b\pmod m\implies a\cdot c\equiv b\cdot c\pmod{m\cdot c}$

$\implies2^{2012}\cdot2\equiv1\cdot2\pmod{5\cdot2}$

Comment: Can this be done using last digits of powers of $2$ as Wojowu describes? that method seems more straightforward? (+1)

Comment: @Amad27< On trial, we observe that the last digit $\pmod{10}$ has a cycle $2,4,8,6$ of period $4$. Now $2013\equiv1\pmod4$

Comment: Wait, why did you go from $\pmod{10}$ to $\pmod{4}$?? So **in mod 10** 2^1 = 1, $2^2 = 4, 2^3 = 8, 2^4 = 6...$ Then how can I use this?

Comment: @Amad27, Observe that $2^{4k+a}-2^a=2^a(16^k-1)\equiv0\pmod{10}$ for $k\ge1$ as $16^k-1$ is divisible by $16-1=15$